# Javascript: How can I Choose a specific Part from an Output

Tags: javascript, object, output, console.log

easy question:

```
 FunctionOutput: Promise {
  _c: 
   [ { promise: [Object],
       resolve: [Function],
       reject: [Function],
       ok: [Function],
       fail: [Function],
       domain: null } ],
  _a: undefined,
  _s: 1,
  _d: true,
  _v: 
   { body: 
      { token_type: 'bearer',
        access_token: 'token',
        expires_in: 7776000,
        refresh_token: 'token' },
     statusCode: 200 },
  _h: 0,
  _n: true }
```

This is my Output from a function and I want to specify output "access_token" How do I do that?

```
console.log("token is"+ data._v.body.access_token);
```

does not work...

Pls help Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: How did you assign the object to `data`? It might very well be that you assigned a *promise* to `data`, not the promised value, which can only be retrieved asynchronously.

Comment: have you debugged to into the code to see if data, _v and body are populated with values or are undefined? Which part "does not work"?

Comment: How are you getting `data`?

Comment: What's the output you're getting from `console.log("token is"+ data._v.body.access_token);`? is it undefined? are you getting an error? please explain more, so we can help

Answer (score 0):

What you've shown is a **promise**. You'd use the promise via its `then` method:

```
data
.then(function(result) {
    // Use result here
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // Handle error here
});
```

We can't tell you how to access `access_token` on the result, because we don't know what part of what you've shown (if any) will be the resolution value. It *may* be `result.access_token`, or `result.body.access_token`. But you won't be able to access it except in a `then` callback.

```
data
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.body.access_token);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // Handle error here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring if you just want to have the access_token

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```js
// whatever you're calling that returns that object
const mockRequest = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(res))
// response
const res = {
  body: {
    token_type: 'bearer',
    access_token: 'token',
    expires_in: 7776000,
    refresh_token: 'token'
  },
  statusCode: 200
}

/*
  calls async function it then waits until its 
  finsihed the request and "then" calls the then with the data

  Normally we would just return what ever comes back
  i.e (data) => data.body.access_token
  But we can use a new ES6 feature which just returns the object
  name passed instead 
  i.e ({body}) => { token_type: 'bearer' ... 
*/

function getAccess() {
  mockRequest()
    .then(({body: {access_token}}) => console.log(access_token))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

getAccess();

/*
  // Or using es7 features such as async await
  async function getAccessES7() {
    const {body:{access_token}} = await mockRequest();
    return access_token;
  }
  getAccessES7();
*/
```